# localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

Помогите как решить данную проблему 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
 Ошибка при указании соединения для controluser в конфигурации.
 mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Не надо это вписывать комментарием к вопросу - нужно вписать в вопрос.